# SQLite select blob with NUL characters

Tags: android, sqlite, busybox

I'm having trouble getting a blob out of a SQLite database. When I attempt a SELECT statement, I only get a few characters up to the first NUL and then it stops.

My goal is to save the blob as a zip file (which is what the blob is) for further processing with another application. I am able to successfully get the hex version of the blob via SELECT hex(data), but that doesn't help me as it is not formatted correctly. I'm using BusyBox on an Android phone and there is a hexcode -r command that can reverse the hex output, but it only works if it's formatted as Canonical hex+ASCII display. Thus, I want to get the blob text as I will be able to simply save that as a zip file.

So, how can I get the whole blob including NUL characters? I've read about binding, but I don't quite understand it. If that is the solution, how would I write it in a shell command for Android with Busybox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working at this for about 8 hours straight, I finally got what I needed. Here is the command I used:

```
echo -ne "$(echo | sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/databases/model.db "SELECT HEX(data) FROM conversations LIMIT 1;" | sed -e 's/../\\x&/g')" > /sdcard/output.zip
```

The result is the zip file that was stored as a blob in the database. I hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

NULs are interpreted as terminators when you try to treat the blob as a string.

Ensure that blobs are *always* accessed as blobs, i.e., don't try to do any string operations with the value in SQL, use functions like [getBlob](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html#getBlob%28int%29) instead of `getString`, and use byte arrays instead of strings:

```java
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT data FROM ...", ...);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(".../data.gz");
    GZIPOutputStream compressor = new GZIPOutputStream(file);
    compressor.write(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to get the blob out as a zip file using shell commands so it can be done via terminal emulator or adb shell. How can I modify your code to work in that medium? I tried it after initializing sqlite3 and it said syntax error near cursor.